# Ember double each loop. Using value of inner each loop variable to bind to property named the same in the variable of the outer each loop

Tags: javascript, ember.js, each, htmlbars

To elaborate on the title, what I am trying to achieve is the following.

I am building an interactive table component in Ember. Here is the stripped template:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {{#each header in headers}}
                <th>{{header}}</th>
            {{/each}}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each row in rows}}
        <tr>
            {{#each header in headers}}
                <td>{{input value=row.[header]}}</td> <!-- can I bind to row.header here somehow? -->
            {{/each}}
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want each input field for a specific row and specific column, to be bound to that row's `row` object, specifically to a property named the way the header column is named.

Essentially, I want to use the value of the header variable to bind a property in the row object called by that value (If current header has value `'title'` then I want to bind to `row.title`)

Here is an example of how I initialize these objects:

```
var headers = ['title','description'];

var rows = [],
    row = {};

for(var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
    row[headers[i]] = '';  // this line does similar thing to what I am trying to achieve
}

rows.push(row);

/* This gives

    rows = [
        {
            title: '',
            description: ''
        }
    ]
*/
```

After researching, I found [**this**](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html) in the Handlebars documentation that says I can access properties like this:

```
{{#each articles.[10].[#comments]}}
    ...
{{/each}}
```

Which is, according to the docs, pretty much the same as:

```
articles[10]['#comments']
```

However, using:

```
rows.[header]
```

doesn't work for me because it tries to literally access the `'header'` property of the `rows` object (i.e. `rows.header`) and not the value contained in the header variable.

Comment: By design, Handlebars does not permit this degree of "logic" in templates. You'll have to do some prepping of your data in the controller or view, to get it into a shape where Handlebars can spit it out easily.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if there was some way of accessing these properties that isn't documented by Handlebars or at least not in the obvious places. Even though I would prefer doing things the way I mentioned here and it would be much cleaner that way, I coded a workaround that does what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality can now easily be achived in Ember ([since 1.13](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/05/10/run-up-to-two-oh.html)) using the new and awesome inline helpers [mut](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_mut) and [get](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_get):

The way to achieve this is in two basic steps:

1. Use `get` to dynamically lookup a property from `r` named as whatever the value of `h` is at that `each` iteration. For example, if `h = 'title'`, then this would return `r['title']`.
2. Use `mut` to specify that this extracted value is mutable by our input component (specifically its value property).

This is how the whole `each` looks:

```
{{#each rows as |r|}}
<tr>
  {{#each headers as |h|}}
  <td>
    <input onkeyup={{action (mut (get r h)) value="target.value" }}>
  </td>
  {{/each}}
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

#### Detailed example on Ember Twiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can always extend the textfield component and at least get the value you are looking for.

```
App.DynamicInputComponent = Ember.TextField.extend({
  row: null,
  col: null,
  value: function(){
    var row = this.get('row');
    var col = this.get('col');

    return row[col];
  }.property('row', 'col')
});
```

Then, in your template you can do:

```
<table>
  {{#each item in model}}
  <tr>
    {{#each col in columns}}
      <td> {{ dynamic-input type='text' row=item col=col }} </td>
    {{/each}}
  </tr>
  {{/each}}
</table>
```

(Partially) working solution [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yoqase/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Not exactly what I need. I am not interested in the value of `row[col]` but i want to bind the value of the input field to the property `col` in the `row` object so it is automatically computed by Ember each time the user types something in.